# Wygwam Adding Extra Span Tags with Font-Size Style

Tags: add-on, wygwam, pixelandtonic

I am running into an error when editing content in Chrome on Mac. I upgraded to Wygwam v2.7 to ensure I was using the latest version. I am using EE v2.5.3.

When adjusting paragraph text, if I delete the break and merge it with the previous paragraph then create a new paragraph, SPAN tags are being added. You can see the example in this video, http://cl.ly/3S2N0z2p1G3p

Any ideas what is causing the issue?

Comment: Hey Mike - if you try that on the CKEditor demo page, does the problem show up? http://ckeditor.com/demo.  Please let me know, thank you!

Comment: In the demo, a SPAN tag is added but it has line-height instead of font-size. <span style="line-height: 1.6em;">

Comment: The undesirable part is the span tag at all, yes? It sounds like it may be a CKE issue here.

Comment: Yes, in the error I am running into, the span tag is using the font-size style. This causes some issues on the front-end of the site because the font-size is being adjusted. So there isn't much to do if it is an issue with CKEditor?

Comment: Well, we're not on CKE 4 yet, but there is an existing bug report: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998 so it does look like a CKE issue, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Ahh, bummer. Thanks for the help and finding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this may be a [bug with CKEditor](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998)  That bug report is for v4, but looks like it may also impact v3.x as well.

Answer (score 2):

As a good stop gap solution, Tyssen suggested that I add this code to my CSS: `span[style]: line-height: inherit !important; font-size: inherit !important;`